# Define "/inicio" as homepage or workaround routes miss configuration

Tags: php, symfony

I have a site with some static pages and I have defined as follow in `routing_pages.yml` file:

```
index:
    pattern:  /inicio
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:index.html.twig' }

contact_one:
    pattern:  /contact_one
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:contact.html.twig' }

location:
    pattern:  /horario
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:location.html.twig' }

payment:
    pattern:  /pagos
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:payment.html.twig' }

question:
    pattern:  /preguntas
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:question.html.twig' }

questionb:
    pattern:  /preguntasb
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:questionb.html.twig' }

shipping:
    pattern:  /politicasenvio
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:shipping.html.twig' }

warranties:
    pattern:  /garantias
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:warranties.html.twig' }

ml:
    pattern:  /ml
    defaults: { template: 'FrontendBundle:Site:forms.html.twig' }
```

Then at main `routing.yml` file I use the resource as:

```
_paginas:
    resource: routing_pages.yml
    prefix:   /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
```

I'm having some issues trying to access `/app_dev.php|app.php` route with this exception:

> No route found for "GET /"

This is due to the configuration I have on `access_control` at `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    #Security Login/Register/Resetting
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #Frontend Pages Routes
    - { path: ^/inicio, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/contact_one, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/horario, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/pagos, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/preguntas, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/preguntasb, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/politicasenvio, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/garantias, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/ml, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    #Login required
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

What I did like that? Because the stactic pages doesn't need login features just admin area does. I tried play with this two lines by changing to this:

```
    - { path: ^/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But then when I access `app_dev.php|app.php/admin I don't see the login form, why? How I fix that? Any advice?

If I could define `/inicio` as `homepage` in somewhere or somehow then the problem is fixed, tough, but I don't know how to.

Comment: Why not just let the rules that are only for `*_ADMIN` role? In my `security.yml` it's only added the paths where the ADMIN can only access or where a logged user can access

Comment: @tttony I don't follow you, what you try to show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just define a redirect from "/" to "/inicio" in the routing table:

```
# redirecting the root
root:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /inicio
        permanent: true
```

src: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_in_config.html